# FFT of very noisy non-periodic signal

Tags: python, fft

I'm pretty new to python and have only done one course in it last semester. Basically I want to Fourier transform a plot profile of a polymer image which looks like this:

[image]

I've tried a few different ways of doing it but it gives me nothing, probably because of how noisy it is and the fact that it's non-periodic so i was just wondering if it's actually possible to do it?

Here's my code so far:

```
%matplotlib inline
import pylab as plt
import numpy as np
from math import pi
from scipy.fftpack import fft

x = open('20x0.5hr.txt')
Yvalues = []
for line in x:
    a,b = line.split()
    Yvalues.append(b)

FuncFFT=fft(Yvalues)
FuncFFT=np.abs(FuncFFT)
plt.plot(FuncFFT[:100])
plt.show()
```

Thanks.

Comment: I may be wrong, but looking at your plot it seems that there is a contribution from a wavelength longer than your sample.  Have you any possibility to have longer samples to work on?

Comment: Two questions; What does your plot show, and can you post the data somewhere?

Comment: Exactly what do you mean by "gives me nothing"?  What did it give you?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like something is going on, starting at some frequency then increasing, but noisily and erratically.  Or perhaps it stops after the first few cycles, and there's a burst of somewhat higher frequency noise in the middle of that data run.  I assume this is the part of the signal of interest.  There's also a droopy trend. Perhaps the high-frequency noise is doing something interesting, varying in amplitude or having some spectral structure.

If the long-term trend is of no interest, you can always subtract it out with a high-pass filter which lets everything through but the loweste frequencies (1 to a few cycles per run of data as shown), or fit a low-order polynomial and subtract.  The highest-frequency noise can be reduced, if it's of no interest, with a low pass filter.  I tend to be a Savitzky-Golay fanboy, and I'd probably use a 4th order and width about half the width of that first big positive peak.  I usually remove stuff I don't care about, for initial data exploration, just to make the interesting part easier to see and fit curves to.

Because of my impression of increasing frequency, I'd probably resample the data nonlinearly.  Instead of y vs. x,   I'd define a new x' which stretches the right part of the data more than the left part. I'd try plt.plot(x*x, y) and toy with various expression until I think I see uniformly spaced peaks.  Of course, a theoretical understanding of the instrumentation and physical phenomenon would help narrow the possibilities. Then I'd resamaple the data, so I have values y' on a uniform grid of x' points, then look at the Fourier power spectrum.

Then again, I might look at the Fourier power spectrum right off, before any cleaning or nonlinear stretching.  Whether immediately or after some processing, the power spectrum is computed in a couple lines. It's easier to deal with the logarithm of it.

```
f = fft(b)
p = np.log( np.real( f * np.conj(f) ) )
plt.plot(p)
```

Plotting only the real part, or just the imaginary part, of f, does not reveal insightful information.  You may be seeing the cosine part but not the sine part - that is, what you see in the plot is sensitive to time shifts of the signal.  To see if a periodic signal is present in noise, you must look at the power spectrum.

Finally, have you looked at the Signal Processing Stack Exchange site?  https://dsp.stackexchange.com/ . Such questions are dealt with there frequently, though programming language details typically are pushed over to StackOverflow.